# Why shouldn't NetworkManager manage ethernet?

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, networkmanager, ethernet

On Debian, NetworkManager is configured [not to manage ethernet/wired connections](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager#Wired_Networks_are_Unmanaged) by default.

Clearly there was a good reason to set this default. But why? What's the problem with having NM manage ethernet connections?

For context, I am using Debian on a personal laptop. I occasionally need to plug into ethernet, then unplug and switch to wifi, or plug into ethernet and switch from wifi. I'd like this process to be automatic, if possible. Should I set up NetworkManager to manage wired connections? If not, what is the intended workflow using Debian's default configuration?

Comment: Historical preferences I guess. Lots of distros manage all network interfaces via NM.

Comment: You, could make it automatic. There are good reasons for it not to be automatic by default though, as there is a wide range of implications. Many people prefer their OS to NOT be autoconnecting and automounting anything it sees.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the title of the section is misleading. The point is that by default NetworkManager does not manage interfaces managed by `ifupdown` (that is: mentioned in `/etc/network/interfaces`). So just disregard the title while still noting the content. Back in the days of Debian squeeze installation most often happened over Ethernet, thus the installer usually configured the Ethernet interface in `/etc/network/interfaces` because it uses `ifupdown` for managing network connections. So the title was a common corollary of this, once the user installed NetworkManager after the initial network setup.